# GBoard not available in work profile

Tags: keyboard, gboard

I have Microsoft InTune and this makes two categories of apps: managed (work) apps and personal apps. In MS Teams, for example, I have a problem that there is only default Samsung keyboard and I can't switch it to GBoard which I use normally. I tried to find GBoard in the managed Play store, but it's not there. Ideas?

Comment: Unclear if you've seen: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/apps-add-android-for-work and/or requested your device administrators to allow GBoard.

Comment: thx I will ask them if possible